# on an ActiveModel Object, how do I check uniqueness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel, rails-activerecord

In Bryan Helmkamp's excellent blog post called "[7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)", he mentions using `Form Objects` to abstract away multi-layer forms and stop using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

**Edit: see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670396/on-an-activemodel-object-how-do-i-check-uniqueness#14671979) for a solution.**

I've almost exactly duplicated his code sample, as I had the same problem to solve:

```ruby
class Signup
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :user
  attr_reader :account

  attribute :name, String
  attribute :account_name, String
  attribute :email, String

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :account_name,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
    length: 3..40,
    format: { with: /^([a-z0-9\-]+)$/i }

  # Forms are never themselves persisted
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def persist!
    @account = Account.create!(name: account_name)
    @user = @account.users.create!(name: name, email: email)
  end
end
```

One of the things different in my piece of code, is that I need to validate the **uniqueness** of the account name (and user e-mail). However, `ActiveModel::Validations` doesn't have a `uniqueness` validator, as it's supposed to be a non-database backed variant of `ActiveRecord`.

I figured there are three ways to handle this:

- Write my own method to check this (feels redundant)
- Include ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator (tried this, didn't get it to work)
- Or add the constraint in the data storage layer

I would prefer to use the last one. But then I'm kept wondering *how* I would implement this.

I could do something like *(metaprogramming, I would need to modify some other areas)*:

```ruby
  def persist!
    @account = Account.create!(name: account_name)
    @user = @account.users.create!(name: name, email: email)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    errors.add(:name, "not unique" )
    false
  end
```

But now I have two checks running in my class, first I use `valid?` and then I use a `rescue` statement for the data storage constraints.

Does anyone know of a good way to handle this issue? Would it be better to perhaps write my own validator for this (but then I'd have two queries to the database, where ideally one would be enough).

Comment: If this can help anyone: in a similar situation I include "ActiveRecord::Validations" instead of "ActiveModel::Validations" - in this way *validates_uniqueness_of* is available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bryan was kind enough to [comment on my question to his blog post](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/#comment-787150345). With his help, I've come up with the following custom validator:

```ruby
class UniquenessValidator < ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator
  def setup(klass)
    super
    @klass = options[:model] if options[:model]
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # UniquenessValidator can't be used outside of ActiveRecord instances, here
    # we return the exact same error, unless the 'model' option is given.
    #
    if ! options[:model] && ! record.class.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
      raise ArgumentError, "Unknown validator: 'UniquenessValidator'"

    # If we're inside an ActiveRecord class, and `model` isn't set, use the
    # default behaviour of the validator.
    #
    elsif ! options[:model]
      super

    # Custom validator options. The validator can be called in any class, as
    # long as it includes `ActiveModel::Validations`. You can tell the validator
    # which ActiveRecord based class to check against, using the `model`
    # option. Also, if you are using a different attribute name, you can set the
    # correct one for the ActiveRecord class using the `attribute` option.
    #
    else
      record_org, attribute_org = record, attribute

      attribute = options[:attribute].to_sym if options[:attribute]
      record = options[:model].new(attribute => value)

      super

      if record.errors.any?
        record_org.errors.add(attribute_org, :taken,
          options.except(:case_sensitive, :scope).merge(value: value))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it in your ActiveModel classes like so:

```ruby
  validates :account_name,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, model: Account, attribute: 'name' }
```

The only problem you'll have with this, is if your custom `model` class has validations as well. Those validations aren't run when you call `Signup.new.save`, so you will have to check those some other way. You can always use `save(validate: false)` inside the above `persist!` method, but then you have to make sure all validations are in the `Signup` class, and keep that class up to date, when you change any validations in `Account` or `User`.

Comment: Note that in Rails 4.1, `#setup` is deprecated on validators, and will be removed in 4.2. Changing the method to `initialize` should work as-is.

Answer (score 12):

Creating a custom validator may be overkill if this just happens to be a one-off requirement.

A simplified approach...

```rb
class Signup

  (...)

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :account_name, length: {within: 3..40}, format: { with: /^([a-z0-9\-]+)$/i }

  # Call a private method to verify uniqueness

  validate :account_name_is_unique


  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private

  # Refactor as needed

  def account_name_is_unique
    if Account.where(name: account_name).exists?
      errors.add(:account_name, 'Account name is taken')
    end
  end

  def persist!
    @account = Account.create!(name: account_name)
    @user = @account.users.create!(name: name, email: email)
  end
end
```

Comment: This will only work for new objects. When updating the record you will receive an error due to the current object already being in the database.

Comment: This is a Signup form, an action which only occurs once in a given user's lifecycle. :) But your point is understood.  If you were looking to reuse this form object, one approach may be a `#find_or_initialize_by` followed by `#persisted?` to handle each case. An easier alternative approach would be a separate form object for edits and updates to the persisted object.

Comment: I would use `exists?` instead of `count == 0` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F