# Uniqueness validator returns undefined method `new_record?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Im having a problem with my form object for validating uniqueness if username and then I searched answers on how to use uniqueness validation inside form object then I found answer in this question

[on an ActiveModel Object, how do I check uniqueness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670396/on-an-activemodel-object-how-do-i-check-uniqueness)

but unfortunately after I created the UniquenessValidator class it returns an error in my form view,

`` undefined method `new_record?' for #<UserForm:0x007fd40c42d258> ``

How can I resolve this error, Im using Rails 5.1

**UserForm (user_form.rb):**

```
class UserForm
  include Virtus.model

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :username, String
  attribute :password, String
  attribute :company_name, String

  validates :username, presence: { message: '%{attribute} is required'}
  validates :password, presence: { message: '%{attribute} is required'}
  validates :company_name, presence: { message: '%{attribute} is required'}
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, message: '%{attribute} must me
                                             minimum of 6 characters' }
  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, model: User, attribute: :username }

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private

  def persist!
    @company = Company.create!(name: company_name)
    @company.users.create!(username: username, password: password,
                           user_type: 'Owner')
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post you code here

Comment: I am guessing you dont have a model

Comment: @MayurShah I updated my post, code for my form object has been included

Comment: @Fallenhero I have a model look at my code

Comment: No. You dont have a model. That would look like `class UserForm < ActiveRecord::Base`. I dont know why you try with `include`s.

Comment: @Fallenhero why do I need to inherit the ActiveRecord::Base? I think the model is  this model: User

Comment: Have you tried using the api to look up solutions?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: Also is the error present if you modify the definition of persist! to not create the users?

Comment: One last part ... do you have an key index setup on the user_name field in the database?

Comment: @Mirv what do you mean by index setup?

Comment: I copy the UniquenessValidator from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670396/on-an-activemodel-object-how-do-i-check-uniqueness

Comment: Try the link I posted instead, then read down after the description there's a description of why index's are necessary if you want uniqueness in db ... the rails validation is just a precheck for the database's own integrity enforcement (if you haven't studied indexes & unique keys you'll need to look that up next or your database will be hosed one day)... quick link for setting up index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370271/a-migration-to-add-unique-constraint-to-a-combination-of-columns

Comment: @Mirv I already setup unique index in my table still it returns same error

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined Aug 8th at 11:46 yet?  I'm still waiting on confirmation from that - unless you directly answer the questions I can't help.

Comment: thanks for the help, maybe I will use reform gem to make validating uniqueness work

Answer (score 1):

The new_record? method comes from the ActiveRecord::Persistence module. I doubt you can simply include it, because your model isn't a typical subclass of ActiveRecord::Base.

Here's a quick and dirty solution that might do what you need:

```
validates :username, if: :new_username?

# ...

private

def new_username?
    User.where(username: username).empty?
end
```

Note that this will only work correctly if you're creating a new user. Updating an existing user will always fail. (Based on the code you posted, it looks like that's how you're using this model anyway.)

Comment: basically there's an update, so I need the validator to work both create and update